# MySQL Count in select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

i have a MySQL table with the username and bought items. Like…

```
Username1 - Item_A
Username1 - Item_A
Username2 - Item_C
Username2 - Item_D
```

I need to count how many differed Itemy every user has bought.

Like:

```
Username1 - 1
Username2 - 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the user and apply a distinct count to the items:

```
SELECT   username, COUNT(DISTINCT item)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY username
```